# Java log file contains duplicated records

Tags: java, linux, windows, logging, duplicates

I use sfl4j log framework.
I run code on Windows and on Linux.
I use same log properties on both OS.

Log file on ***Windows*** is looking fine.
Log file on ***Linux*** sometimes contains 2 or 3 absolutely same records including time stamp (with milliseconds). These records have ***TRACE*** level.
I understand that I made some mistake in log properties but why behavior is different for Windows and Linux. 
Any ideas?
log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout, file
log4j.category.audit=TRACE,audit
log4j.category.audit.additivity.audit=false
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/customer-backend.log
log4j.appender.file.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern= %d{dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss} %1p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.audit=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.audit.File=${catalina.home}/logs/spa-web-audit.log
log4j.appender.audit.Append=true
log4j.appender.audit.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.audit.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.audit.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans.factory=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=INFO
log4j.logger.audit=TRACE
log4j.logger.com.clicksmob.backoffice.customer.svc.periodic=TRACE
log4j.logger.com.clicksmob.backoffice.customer.svc.periodic.actions.offers.media=WARN
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add your logging configuration ?

Comment: I added log4j.properties into message.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. For Linux by mistake was used incorrect log4j property file.